# Trying to compile GTK application for 32bit linux from 64bit linux

Tags: linux, gcc, gtk, cross-platform, cpu-architecture

I am trying to compile a GTK application for 32bit linux from 64bit linux.

When I run this command:

```
gcc main.c -m32 -mms-bitfields -o output/main `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0` && ./output/main
```

I get these errors:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgtk-3
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgdk-3
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -latk-1.0
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgio-2.0
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpangocairo-1.0
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcairo-gobject
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpango-1.0
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcairo
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgobject-2.0
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lglib-2.0
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Running Linux Mint 17.2 Rafaela.

I have all the required packages and I've even included the `-m32` option but it still doesnt work.

There is also a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8258778/3470343) which doesn't have an accepted answer.

**Edit:**

The accepted answer below suggested I install the 32bit version of `libgtk-3-dev`. I could not do this without removing important system packages. In the end I resorted to simply using a 32bit linux distro with the 32bit version of `libgtk-3-dev` installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could run:

```
apt-get install libgtk-3-dev:i386
```

then rerun your compile command and it should work. If the above command returns an error saying it cannot find the package specified, you may need to run this, then try again:

```
dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

**Warning:** If the command above asks you to remove packages, read the list carefully, if the list includes important system packages or if you are unsure then do not proceed.

Comment: How do I undo the effects of `dpkg --add-architecture i386`, I tried `sudo dpkg --remove-architecture i386` but I got this error - `dpkg: error: cannot remove architecture 'i386' currently in use by the database`

Comment: Did you remove libgtk-3-dev:i386 and all its dependencies?

Comment: I didn't install it. I stopped when it said it wanted to remove a bunch of packages, one of them was the desktop environment.

Comment: Found the solution/explanation. [link](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/295273/122397)

Comment: Well, thanks for accepting it. You could answer the way you actually did it, though, and accept that one. I don't mind this one being accepted, but I'd like the accepted answer to be the one that actually solves the problem.

Comment: Why do you need to `dpkg --add-architecture i386`?  `libgtk-3-dev:i386` is already visible in the package list on a normal multi-arch x86-64 Ubuntu system.  Does Mint not do multi-arch the same way?

Comment: @PeterCordes, Sorry, maybe you don't. I'm coming from Debian experience here, if that's wrong I'll update the answer.

Comment: @oldtechaa: I think Debian does multiarch the same as Ubuntu these days.  In the old days before the current multiarch setup, i386 versions of everything weren't normally available.  I'd comment out the `dpkg --add-architecture i386` command, and mark it with a "probably not necessary" comment.

Comment: @PeterCordes, in Debian, last I knew, you must use `add-architecture` to see _any_ i386 packages, but I will change it.

Comment: See https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch.  `the immediate practical effects are getting rid of the ia32-libs package, and allowing proper cross-architecture dependencies for cross-building.`  According to that wiki, `dpkg` became multiarch-aware in 2011.